# Template class optionally inserting initial values in as template parameter

Tags: c++, class, templates

I currently have a class that is equivalent to:

```
template <class T>
class MyContainer
{
public:
  MyContainer():
    _value()
  {
  }

  T DoSomething();

private:
  T _value;
};
```

I would like to make it so that I can enter the inital value in as a template parameter, something like the following:

```
template <class T> constexpr T GetInital()
{
  return 0;
}

template <> constexpr std::string GetInital()
{
  return "";
}

template <class T, T initial = GetInital<T>()>
class MyContainer
{
public:
  MyContainer():
    _value(initial)
  {
  }

  T DoSomething();

private:

  T _value;
};

MyContainer<std::string> string_container; // initalized to ""
MyContainer<std::string, "hello"> string_container2; // initalized to hello
MyContainer<int> int_container; // initalized to 0
MyContainer<int, 43> int_container; // initalized to 43
```

But it does not like classes with a "non trivial destructor" like std::string. Is what I'm trying to do possible and is there a way around this.

Comment: This is unlikely to work out the way you want; `MyContainer<int>` and `MyContainer<int, 43>` are *completely different types.* This means that if you have an `std::vector<MyContainer<int>>` you *cannot* add a `MyContainer<int, 43>` to this container without a conversion operator/constructor. Template arguments should not be used just to supply what is essentially a constructor argument; just use a `constexpr` constructor.

Comment: You can't use a `std::string` as a non-type parameter.

Comment: @RSahu but he can simulate it with a typelist and a user defined literal + `decltype`

Answer (score 3):

Just write a constructor overload to do the initialization, its exactly what it is designed for.

As others noticed, each combination of template parameters generates a completely different type. And discussing a possible solution to that (Compile-time type erasure?) is meaningless for a situation well covered by one of the fundamental features of C++: constructors

```
template <class T>
class MyContainer
{
public:
  MyContainer():
    _value()
  {
  }

  MyContainer(const T& init):
    _value(init)
  {
  }

  T DoSomething();

private:
  T _value;
};

MyContainer<std::string> string_container;           // initalized to ""
MyContainer<std::string> string_container2{"hello"}; // initalized to hello
MyContainer<int> int_container;                      // initalized to 0
MyContainer<int> int_container{43};                  // initalized to 43
```

If what you wanted is a `typedef` whose instances are always initialized to a value you specified, just write a factory function:

```
template<typename T> 
auto make_factory( const T& init )
{
    return [=](){ return MyContainer<T>{ init }; };
}

int main()
{
    auto factory = make_factory<std::string>( "hello" );

    auto c1 = factory(); //c1 initialized to hello
    auto c2 = factory(); //c2 initialized to hello
}
```

*Actually, `make_factory()` is a factory of factories...*

Comment: `: _value()` is implied in default, empty implementation, no?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz yes. I'm a big fan of the Rule Of Zero, but I just modified what the OP did. Even if you write it, prefer `MyContainer() = default;`